# Метод HTTP реквеста для получения сообщения Telegram

Tags: telegram-bot, telegram

С помощью метода `GetUpdates` можно получить список чатов, в которых есть обновления.
Вопрос в том, какой метод можно использовать для получения непосредственно текста сообщения из чата? В документации не нашёл

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Этот же метод и возвращает текст сообщения в чате.

```
 {
  "ok":true,
  "result":[
  {
    "update_id":99962446,
    "message":{
    "message_id":14,
    "from":{},
    "chat":{},
    "date":1668342407,
    "text":"Hello world"
  }
 }
 ]
}
```